# Drag not functioning in frameless window in electron 14 and 15

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, draggable

I have been successfully using the [official documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#draggable-region) to get frameless draggable windows in electron. It worked just fine with electron 10.x, I recently updated to 13.3 and it worked as well. But since version 14 and 15 the drag doesn't work anymore on Windows machines (works fine on Mac).

I double checked that my div had a proper width and height and that it had the `-webkit-app-region: drag` property, and that no other element was overlapping.

The last comments in this [old-closed-related issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3647) seem to indicate that I am not the only one facing this issue.

Has anybody the same issue ? Solved it ?

Should I open a new issue on the electron repository ?

Comment: is [this](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30788) what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you pushkin, I just read [the issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30788) you mentioned, and tested on my project by setting the `resizable` parameter to true and my window was again draggable. This confirms that I am facing the same bug.

So the answer is : follow [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/30788) to keep updated